# GPS tracker coordinate conversion into google maps format and preciseness

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, gps

I own gps tracker that send latitude and longitude to my server, as it is described in gps tracker manual(example for Latitude, for Longitude the same):

```
xxmm.dddd, where
xx = degrees;
mm = minutes;
dddd = decimal part of minutes; for example 11 deg. 26.6639 min.
```

I`d like to convert received coordinates into google maps format, for this purpuse I am using formula:

```
result = xx + (mm.dddd)/60
```

since, there is a division result could be presented as periodically fraction, for example - 1.6666(6), but it is very bad cause I am loosing so much of GPS preciness.

Questions

1. What is the name of format I am receiving coordinates?
2. What is the name of format that google maps are using?
3. What is the best formula to conversate received gps locations into google maps format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. degrees, minutes, seconds
2. decimal degrees
3. decimal degrees = degrees + (minutes/60) + (seconds/3600)

Comment: But, anyway since there is still divide operation - what about loosing preciseness?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to convert DDD MM.MMM to Decimal Degress, I assume that you know the North South East or West for that location.

1. The format name is DMS (Degress Minutes & Seconds) that is Geographic coordinate system.
2. The format for google maps is Decimal degress.
3. For convert DMS to Decimal degress: D + (M/60) + (S/3600) like **Galen** said.

Example Latitude:

```
int xD = 020;
int xM = 10;
int xS = 7587;
```

Example Longitude:

```
int yD = 130;
int yM = 50;
int yS = 5475;
```

Conversion:

```
Lat = 020+(10/60)+(7587/3600);
Lon = 130+(50/60)+(5475/3600);
```