# Converting GPS Co-ordinates to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, gps, latitude-longitude

This is a weird one. I have a GPS device which is kicking back this info:

Lon:115.91080W
Lat:5222.70110N

It can also kick this back as a Google maps link, which shows this:

Lon:-1.26518
Lat:+52.37835

Can anyone suggest how the system converts between the two data points internally? I found [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091530/gps-tracker-coordinate-conversion-into-google-maps-format-and-preciseness) which seems somewhat similar but the conversions don't seem to add up :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That post works for me assuming the format is DDMM.MMMM (D=degrees, M=minutes)

115.91080W -> 1 + 15.91080/60 = 1.26518 (W -> -)           =  -1.26518
5222.7011N -> 52 + 22.7011/60 = 52.3783516666666 (N -> +)  = +52.37835

Why do you think the "conversions don't seem to add up"?

Comment: Ah, you're right! I was taking the bit after the decimal as seconds but I see now that it is Degrees followed by decimal minutes. Thanks :)