# converting long lat to google maps long lat

Tags: c#, google-maps, coordinates

I'm having some trouble getting accurate readings from a GPRS tracker, implementing the coordinates given into gMaps api.

I've read here that you should convert the minutes / degrees by dividing them by 60 and 3600 respectively, but even trying this i can't get anything TOO accurate:

[GPS tracker coordinate conversion into google maps format and preciseness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091530/gps-tracker-coordinate-conversion-into-google-maps-format-and-preciseness)

the trackers sends packets with the following information;

```
5242.8157 North
00126.3539 West
```

Which i translate as;

```
latitude: 52 degrees, 42 minutes, 8157 seconds - > 52.428157
longitude: -1 degree, 26 minutes, 3539 seconds - > -1.263539
```

But this puts a marker significantly off where i am. Is there something i'm missing here, perhaps something simple that someone might know to do just the trick for more precision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decimal part of your input data (e.g. .8157) is not seconds; it is decimal minutes.  So it should be:

latitude 52 degrees, 42.8157 minutes
or
52.7136 degrees

Comment: I was just about to hit enter on my answer. To expand on the answer, this would be 52 degrees, 42 minutes, and 48.942 seconds (.8157*60). Or as you said 52.7136 degrees (52 + 42.8157/60).

Comment: Worked a charm! Was just me not really understand long and lat i guess!